# Place one div to the right of another CSS

Tags: html, css

This question might look duplicate but it isn't. I have 5 divs. I only want to place div 2 to the right of div 4 using CSS. How can I do that? I have gone through all the present questions on placing one div to the right of other but they only include 2 divs while asking for one div to be place on the right of other. What if there were more than 2 divs. Also I don't want other divs 1,3 and 5 to be effected.

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="div1">
    div1
   </div>
   <div class="div2">
    div2 to be place on right of div4
   </div>
   <div class="div3">
    div3
   </div>
   <div class="div4">
    div4 to be placed on left of div2
   </div>
   <div class="div5">
    div5
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use flex-box https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Will this effect the other divs? since I only want div 2 and 4 to be effected. The divs 1,3 and 5 should remain how they are.

Comment: by using flex box you can basically control which element in the flex container to align. please take look in to the guide I attached :)

Comment: Okay I'll look into it. Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With flexbox and order, you can control the exact display-order of the elements.

Comment: Will this effect the other divs? since I only want div 2 and 4 to be effected. The divs 1,3 and 5 should remain how they are.

Comment: Flexbox only changes the visual order, so you can specify the order exactly as you wish. Look up the specifications.